# How to include Eigen in C++ library after installing libeigen3-dev package

Tags: opencv, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to build [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) from Source (master branch) using cmake.

I installed Eigen package via apt-get.

> sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev

It was successfully installed, and cmake prints that eigen 3.3.4 is installed.

> Eigen:     YES(ver 3.3.4)

But when I did 'make', it showed the error

```
/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp:66.12: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
#  include <Eigen/Core>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation teminated.
```

Comment: You include Eigen by adding its main-directory to the include path. This looks more like an issue with the OpenCV build system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [same question](https://superuser.com/questions/1441375/opencv-failed-compilation-eigen-core-no-such-file-or-directory-cannot-chan) on superuser.

So as the answer did, I have changed cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake from line 44 to 59.

After I have commented out line 46-48 and 59,
and changed `find_package(Eigen3 QUIET)` in line 44 to `find_package(Eigen3 3.0.0)`, it works.

And this problem only happens on OpenCV 4.0 version.

When I install OpenCV 3.4.6 version(tag 3.4.6 on github), this problem does not occur.